# replacing file variables by envsubst in jenkins pipeline

Tags: linux, jenkins

I want to replace some variables in a file having $variablename, at runtime from jenkins pipeline script. It seems envsubst is the best for my use case. When i execute by command line on linux server its working fine but when i'm executing through jenkins pipeline in sh script, nothing happens.

sonar-scanner.properties:

sonar.projectKey=Project:MavenTest$BRANCHNAME
sonar.projectName=MavenTest$BRANCHNAME

Example of Command line on linux box:

> $ export BRANCHNAME=develop
>
> $ envsubst '$BRANCHNAME'

Output:

> sonar.projectKey=Project:MavenTestdevelop
>
> sonar.projectName=MavenTestdevelop

But when i'm executing through jenkins file as a script, nothing is changed in file.

jenkins script:

```
 node {

    stage('checkout'){

        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: ':^(?!origin/master$|origin/develop$).*']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'c0ce73db-3864-4360-9c17-d87caf8a9ea5', url: 'http://172.16.4.158:17990/scm/ctoo/testmaven.git']]])

    }

    stage('initialize variables'){
        // Configuring BRANCH_NAME variable
        sh 'git name-rev --name-only HEAD > GIT_BRANCH'
        sh label: '', script: 'cut -d \'/\' -f 3 GIT_BRANCH > BRANCH'
        branchname = readFile('BRANCH').trim()
        env.BRANCHNAME = branchname
    }
        stage('build & SonarQube analysis') {
            withSonarQubeEnv('Sonar') {
                sh "envsubst '$BRANCHNAME' <sonar-scanner.properties"
              }
        }
}
```

Output:
[Pipeline] sh (hide)

- envsubst repotest

sonar.projectKey=Project:MavenTest$BRANCHNAME

sonar.projectName=MavenTest$BRANCHNAME

Can someone please help me

Answer (score 0):

Hi I don't have idea about the envbust but this can be achieved by passing sonar parameters via command line to the sonar see the below example:

```
withSonarQubeEnv('Sonar') {
            sh "<sonarscanner path> -Dsonar.projectKey=Project:MavenTest$BRANCHNAME"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solved it by using his escape character
`\`,
for example:

```
sh "envsubst '\${SERVER_NAME}' < ./config/nginx/nginx.conf.template > ./config/nginx/nginx.conf"
```